# VSCode introduce an extra space every time the document is formatted

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs3

Whenever the document is formatted, VSCode adds a white space like this

```
<p v-for="      message       in       storeMessage      ">{{ message }}</p>
```

I've tried everything, removed Prettier, set "editor.formatOnSave": false, changed tab size,render whitespace and nothing seems to work, to the point where it ends up looking like this:

```
<p v-for="         message          in          storeMessage         ">{{ message }}</p>
```

but it only happens in the template of vue when I have an v-for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Te problem was this

```
"[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
  },
```

Volar was formatting the code and provcating the extra space. That line was in the settings.json the config file ov VSCode.